# Is it necessary to send statusCode while returning a response from the lambda function using node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('File Uploaded Successfully.')
};

return response;
```

Comment: Hi, What are you using the Lambda function for?

Comment: I hope this article may help you https://link.medium.com/EQnZ4nINI6

Comment: @mokugo-devops to save a file on the S3 bucket using its URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking at lambda template, which include statusCode in the return but there is no requirement to return a status code, or in fact, anything at all.